# Unexpected char error

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this script?

```
#pragma strict

private var dead = false;

function OnControllerColliderHit(hit : ControllerColliderHit) 
{
    if(hit.gameObject.tag == "Respawn")
    {
        dead = true;
    }   
} 

function Update ()
{
    if(dead)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3(0,0,0);
        dead = false;
    } 
}
}
```

Comment: 1. This doesn't look like _JavaScript_. 2. You have a trailing `}` with no matching `{`

Comment: Why do you think there's something wrong with it?  If you're getting an error message from something, please post it.

Comment: Tell us what error/unwelcome behaviour you are seeing? To Paul S. - unity uses a language based on JS but you are correct in that it isn't JS.

Comment: Yes i did get an error it says unexpected char: 'p'. (BCE0044)
Thanks

Comment: What is the location of that error? Is it on `private var dead = false`?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last `}` from the last line or either copy and paste this one:

```
#pragma strict

private var dead = false;

function OnControllerColliderHit(hit : ControllerColliderHit) 
{
    if(hit.gameObject.tag == "Respawn")
    {
        dead = true;
    }   

} 

function Update ()
{
    if(dead)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3(0,0,0);
        dead = false;
    } 
}
```